# Moving window integration filter matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I need to apply a moving window integration filter to a signal in Matlab, I've found the code below which apparently does it but i don't understand how it works, can someone explain?

```
% Make impulse response
h = ones (1 ,31)/31;
Delay = 15; % Delay in samples

% Apply filter
x6 = conv (x5 ,h);
x6 = x6 (15+[1: N]);
x6 = x6/ max( abs(x6 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it ? It's just a moving average filter - not very well done. It just creates a rectangular window (semiwidth =15) so that each value of the new signal is the average of 31 neighbours of the original value (the original value itself, 15 to the right and 15 to the left). The convolution does the average, the next line corrects the "delay". The last line is just a normalization, it has nothing to do with the averaging filter itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if the code you mention really does a moving window integration filter, but what it does:

- defines the impulse response

then:

```
x6 = conv (x5 ,h);       //this applies the filter
x6 = x6 (15+[1: N]);     //this applies the delay, it should be x6 (Delay+[1:length(x5)])
x6 = x6/ max( abs(x6 )); // this normalizes the response
```